# ng-virtual-keyboard $(...).keyboard is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use [this](https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard) library but when I apply it to my form element I get this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).keyboard is not a function
```

I have added module dependency, included js file in `index.html`, what is wrong?

Comment: It states that it depends on this jQuery plugin https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard

Comment: Sure. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ng-virtual-keyboard`](https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard) states that it depends on [this](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue I am using this in my angular 6 application. I declared `declare var $: any;` in Ts & in ngOnInit i wrote the following code

```
 ngOnInit() {
    $("textarea").keyboard();
  }
```